# [xcode-iPhone]two quick touches

Tags: iphone, xcode, action

**Hello, I would like to know how a button that recognizes a touch and two quick touches**

Answer (score 0):

Try to add following action to Your Button

```
UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat
```

**Example**

```
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 80.0, 50.0);
    [button setTitle:@"Tap Me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchDownRepeat:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat];     
    [self.view addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 0):

This might sound hackish, but you could subclass the UIButton and override the touch events and do you magic if [touch tapCount] == 2.

Don't start throwing stuff! I know it's not elegant.